# Is there a way to mass remove apps that have been installed manually?

Tags: 16.04, uninstall

For example, if I installed netbeans, pycharms, or nvidia drivers straight from their websites. They will come in a .sh, tar.gz, or run format. How can I remove all of them with a few commands?

Comment: Yes you can with some find and kill!

Comment: Usually, the manual installer also provides some way to uninstall. Check each one for more info. If that is inconvenient, then package management systems exist to avoid just that.

Comment: they don't show up in the package management systems you know. And @George I want to remove them not kill them.

Comment: Check Netbeans it should have one, pycharm doesn't!

Comment: Kill means remove sorry for my choice of words :)

Comment: @George, those are just examples. I mean non .deb packages in general.

Comment: One it depends on how you installed, if built from source then `make uninstall`,  if vendor has uninstaller, use that. Else it's search and remove. Using a tool like `locate` or `find` will really help

Comment: Go back in time, and install the packages (`.tar`,`.deb`,`install.py`,...) under `installwatch` from the `checkinstall` package.

Answer (score 1):

There in no single catch-all procedure or algorithm to remove arbitrary software installations from your system since the the removal methods depends on the specific installation method and location of each piece of software.